# How to migrate from CVS to SVN by using cvs2svn tool?

Tags: svn, cvs, cvs2svn

**I want to migrate from CVS to SVN by using cvs2svn tool**. I want a step by step process on how to migrate. I have no idea about the usage of the tools.

Basically I am a java fresher. I dont have knowledge on cvs2svn tool and neither on python too.
But my task is to migrate from CVS repository to SVN repository.
Can any one help me how to do this?
I want complete step by step in a brief way.

I have downloaded **cvs2svn 2.3** tool in C:drive and **Python 2.4.4** in c: drive and **silksvn 1.7.1** tool in c:drive? Now what should I do next? I dont know how to use them to make my task complete.

Please suggest me a step-by-step tutorial or a link or e-book or tell me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a couple of good tutorial:

- [Migrating CVS to SVN with cvs2svn – Basics for a Windows user](https://web.archive.org/web/20120225071833/https://ruthklempel.wordpress.com/2008/04/22/migrating-cvs-to-svn-with-cvs2svn-basics-for-a-windows-user/)
- [HOWTO: smooth CVS to SVN migration (and back again)](http://sam.zoy.org/writings/programming/svn2cvs.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting but I already visited that blog. I didnt get that,,so i posted here. am a little confused wit the processs

Comment: @user1076011 I updated my answer with another tutorial. The instructions in this one seems to be very clear an straightforward.

Comment: When i migrated from cvs to svn .. it migrated successfully by showing all pass completed.. but am unable to see my project in svn repository. where does it resides..? can u help

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that problem :(

Comment: I have a requirement  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731759/i-need-richsimpletogglepanel-functionality-to-richtoolbar

Comment: This is a link only answer -- the first link is broken.